# How do I create this translucent material in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, transparency

how can I create this translucent texture in cycles?

[image]

Comment: if you're talking about the duct tape, maybe a mix between Transparent and Diffuse, with a Noise Texture as factor?

Comment: @moonboots Armchair professional: “Or the Translucent BSDF: It tends to be good at translucent materials.” Lol, it might not work so great here, though. Yeah, a diffuse mix would probably work, or maybe even a translucent transparent mix.

Comment: I was wondering if a duct tape was really translucent actually (and not just transparent)

Comment: But would this give me the slight gradient look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix a *Transparent* with a *Diffuse* node, use a *Noise Texture* as factor of the *Mix Shader*, and use the *Mapping* scale values to stretch the noise the way you want:

[image]